# Tensorflow : Is it possible to identify the data is used for training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I have created text classification model(.pb) using tensorflow. Prediction is good.

Is it possible to check the sentence using for prediction is already used to train the model or not. I need to retrain the model when new sentence is given to model to  predict.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and couldn't find a way to get the train data only with the pb file because that file only stores the features and not the actual train data(obviously),but if you have the dataset,then you can easily verify duh....

I don't think you can ever find the exact train data with only the trained model,cause the model only contains the features and not the actual train data